# Using SSH instead of HTTP to access GitBlit repository

Tags: git, ssh, gitblit

I am setting up a new server with GitBlit. It should by default create and manage repos accesible via ssh, port 29418. For example: `ssh://user@gitblit.mycompany.com:29418/repo.git`

But the new GitBlit forces me to use HTTP with every repo I create (no matter of its permission policy). The only way to access it is via HTTP   `http://user@gitblit.mycompany.com/r/repo.git`

I have GitBlit 1.7.7 war under Tomcat6 (as default webapp, under ROOT dir) behind Apache. The same setup worked for me on previous installation on local VM (both Centos6.7).

I am already lost. Cant use SSH and dont know how to get rid of that /r/ in repo´s path. Is it possible that is caused by jk_module, which I used to connect tomcat with apache instead of proxy in VM?

my .properties:

```
git.sshPort=29418
git.repositoriesFolder = ${baseFolder}/git
git.sshKeysManager = com.gitblit.transport.ssh.FileKeyManager
```

Comment: You say in the title that it's not working, but you never describe what the problem is. What exactly is your problem? In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by moving GitBlit out of the Tomcat's ROOT directory and use rewriteRule on Apache VirtualHost

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteLog logs/apache-mod_rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gitblit-1.7.1.*
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /gitblit-1.7.1/$1 [L,PT]

JkMount /gitblit-1.7.1* worker1
```

Gitblit started to offer SSH afterwards.